# Size of electric wire needed to serve overhead projector and screen off 20 amp breaker

Tags: electrical

I have an electric run of about 100 feet on a 20 amp breaker.  I plan to hook up an overhead projector and automatic screen which this line will be dedicated to serve.  What size of wire should I use?  I gather maybe #10 will suffice, but thought I would ask. Thanks

Comment: Wow! That must be some projector. How many watts is it? If you want to spend extra money on #10 wire go ahead but the #12 should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's a problem with power quality, which there shouldn't be over a 100' run. 12 AWG copper conductors should be fine for a 20 ampere branch circuit.

If the equipment draws 20 amperes on a continuous basis, upgrading to 10 AWG copper can increase power quality. But I doubt your equipment will draw anywhere near that amount of current, so #12 should do fine.